# Tensorflow decision forest custom metric vs. number of trees

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, decision-tree, evaluation

I have created a classification model using tensorflow decision forests. I'm struggling to evaluate how the performance changes vs. number of trees for a non-default metric (in this case PR-AUC).

Below is some code with my attempts.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_decision_forests as tfdf

train = load_diabetes()
X = pd.DataFrame(train['data'])
X['target'] = (pd.Series(train['target']) > 100).astype(int)
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(X)
train_ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(X_train, label="target")   
test_ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(X_test, label="target")   
pr_auc = tf.keras.metrics.AUC( curve='PR',)
tfdf_clf = tfdf.keras.GradientBoostedTreesModel()
tfdf_clf.compile(metrics=[pr_auc])
tfdf_clf.fit(train_ds, validation_data=test_ds,)
```

Now I get very useful training logs using

```
tfdf_clf.make_inspector().training_logs()
#[TrainLog(num_trees=1, evaluation=Evaluation(num_examples=None, accuracy=0.9005518555641174, loss=0.6005926132202148, rmse=None, ndcg=None, aucs=None)),
#TrainLog(num_trees=2, evaluation=Evaluation(num_examples=None, accuracy=0.9005518555641174, loss=0.5672071576118469, rmse=None, ndcg=None, aucs=None)),
```

But it doesn't contain any info on PR-AUC vs. iterations

If I evaluate the model, it only persists PR-AUC at the end of training, although it seens to log some intermediate info.

```
tfdf_clf.evaluate(test_ds)
```

1180/1180 [==============================] - 10s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.6832

How can I find how test-data PR-AUC changes vs. number of trees? I need to specifically use tensforflow decision forest library.

Answer (score 0):

Plot the AUPRC. Area under the interpolated precision-recall curve, obtained by plotting (recall, precision) points for different values of the classification threshold. Depending on how it's calculated, PR AUC may be equivalent to the average precision of the model.It looks like the precision is relatively high, but the recall and the area under the ROC curve (AUC) aren't as high as you might like. Classifiers often face challenges when trying to maximize both precision and recall, which is especially true when working with imbalanced datasets. It is important to consider the costs of different types of errors in the context of the problem you care about. In this example, a false negative (a fraudulent transaction is missed) may have a financial cost, while a false positive (a transaction is incorrectly flagged as fraudulent) may decrease user happiness.

In general, the more trees you use the better get the results. However, the improvement decreases as the number of trees increases, i.e. at a certain point the benefit in prediction performance from learning more trees will be lower than the cost in computation time for learning these additional trees.
Random forests are ensemble methods, and you average over many trees. Similarly, if you want to estimate an average of a real-valued random variable (e.g. the average heigth of a citizen in your country) you can take a sample. The expected variance will decrease as the square root of the sample size, and at a certain point the cost of collecting a larger sample will be higher than the benefit in accuracy obtained from such larger sample.
In your case you observe that in a single experiment on a single test set a forest of 10 trees performs better than a forest of 500 trees. This may be due to statistical variance. If this would happen systematically, I would hypothesize that there is something wrong with the implementation.
Typical values for the number of trees is 10, 30 or 100. I think in only very few practical cases more than 300 trees outweights the cost of learning them (well, except maybe if you have a really huge dataset).

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how I can calculate PR-AUC vs. number of trees for Tensorflow Decision Forest library? I can't see an easy way to do this?

Comment: Hello oli5679, this will help you for PR-AUC calculation.
https://www.kaggle.com/nyk510/using-pr-auc-metrics-in-keras

Comment: Thanks! I can already calculate it using tfdf_clf.evaluate(test_ds) if you see my code above. The problem is I want to calculate it vs. number of trees without having to repeatedly fit different models. The training logs gives me exactly what I want for 'accuracy' and 'loss' vs. # trees and I would like to find the same for PR-AUC.